# Why windows use LPVOID to define a address?

Tags: windows, debugging, memory

I read some code about debugger, and I'm confused about the variable the code use to define memory address. Sometimes it use DWORD, and sometimes it use LPVOID, can anyone tell me that why windows use LPVOID to define address?

Comment: No, it never uses DWORD to represent an address.  That of course won't work in the 64-bit version, an 8-byte address can't fit a 4-byte variable.  So I guess that explains why it uses LPVOID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LPVOID in so-called "hungarian" notation means "long pointer to void", that is `void far *`. The latter originates in 16-bit code and nowadays has no meaning. So, LPVOID now is just the same as `void *`, but the name is still maintained for the compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that there is no guarantee that a pointer value will fit into a DWORD (eg. on a 64-bit OS)

In windows, a DWORD is [explicitly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) a 32 bit int. A LPVOID value is explicitly pointer-size.